# Is it possible to geocode via googles geocoder via city/state/address rather than just address?

Tags: .net, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have created a lot of applications that use the Google Maps Api V3.  I have just run into an instance where I have a city, state, address and I need to geocode off all three of these pieces.  Every example I have seen and currently use in my code go specifically off of address.  What I have and have seen for geocoding are very similar to Google's main example which I have pasted here. :

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

As you can see it is just going off of address, I can't do this for my application as some of my addresses are really vague and will come back with numerous results just wondering if anyone has figured out how to do this?

I searched the forums here and found some similar questions but no real answers.  Any comments/advice are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, completely misinterpreted how this address field works.  You can just shove city state on the end of the address field.

http://www.jasonfulps.com/node/288